# Which Eclipse version is better for salesforce?

Tags: community, eclipse, force.com-ide

Which eclipse version best supports Salesforce?
Helios?
Kepler? or Juno?
which one to prefer

Comment: Kepler is best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to find out which version is supported is to check it on the [Force.com Plugin page:](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation)

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

> Prerequisites *(for the 26 August 2014)*
>   Java SE Development Kit (JDK), Runtime Environment 7
>   —the plug-in will fail to load if you don't have the full Java 7
>   JDK (note: the full JDK is not the default JRE installation on Mac OS
>   X) 
>  **Eclipse Juno (4.2) or Eclipse Kepler (4.3) — the 'Eclipse IDE for Java
>   Developers' distribution is strongly recommended**

Comment: Does Kepler supports direct sync with server?

Comment: @Sindoora You need to check a Kepler documentation for that. If you mean Force.com IDE - yes, it can be in sync with a server.

Comment: i think we have to do manual sync before saving in kepler

Comment: @Sindoora It depends on the Force.com IDE version. In a new version it is set to "work offline" by default.

Comment: earlier i used Helios it worked fine. Later on moved to Kepler.It worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Juno works fine for me. Although I prefer Sublime Text with MavensMate.